# NDSolve problem: WhenEvents detects the event, but the derivative of the function does not change

Tags: differential-equations

I have struggled a lot lately with the combination of NDSolve and WhenEvents. At this point I think it must be a bug of some sort.

I solve a differential equation with NDSolve, using WhenEvents to detect "impacts", i.e., time instants when θ[t]==0. At that time instant, I want to reduce θ'[t] by multiplying it by, say, 0.5.

Here's an example:

```
α = 10 π/180; p = 1.4; αp = 5 g Tan[α]; g = 9.81; tmax = 1;

Eq = θ''[t] + 
    p^2 (Sin[α Sign[θ[t]] - θ[t]] + 
       αp (Sin[1 t] - Cos[8 t])/g Cos[α Sign[θ[t]] - θ[t]]) == 0;

s = NDSolve[{Eq, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[θ[t] == 0, {Print[t], θ'[t] -> 0.5 θ'[t]}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]}, θ, {t, 0, 1}];
```

When I run the code, it detects an impact successfully (as t is printed), around 0.43 seconds:

[image]

Yet the derivative is not changed. If I plot θ'[t], it shows that "something" happens to θ'[t], like a change in its slope, but there is no step change as I would expect.

[image: θ[t]]

If I change the code into:

```
s = NDSolve[{Eq, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[θ[t] == 0.000001, {Print[t], θ'[t] -> 0.5 θ'[t]}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]}, θ, {t, 0, 1}];
```

i.e., when I change θ[t] == 0 into θ[t] == 0.000001, within the WhenEvent, then the change in derivative works:

[image: θ'[t] as it should be]

I have experienced similar problems with other excitation functions instead of αp (Sin[1 t] - Cos[8 t])/g, which is just an example. Sometimes even if I put 0.000001 in the event, the derivative sometimes changes, sometimes doesn't. I have tried all "detection method" options too.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: I think it works if you change the action to `{Print[t]; \[Theta]'[t] -> 0.5 \[Theta]'[t]}` (change comma to semicolon).  `Print` returns `Null`, so in the comma form the action is `{Null, ... -> ...}` which is not a list of valid actions because of the `Null`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works, but in other examples the problem remains. I honestly do not know what to do.